# Kotlin script can't access META-INF resources (persistence.xml) from jar

Tags: jpa, kotlin

I have a kotlin script .kts which uses a META-INF resources (persistence.xm) from a jar.

I checked that the META-INF is present in the jar (lib.jar)

```
var emf: EntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, props)
```

I am getting this error when compiling :

> kotlinc -script template2.kts -cp "lib.jar:persist-0.0.1-dev.jar"
>
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager

The same code compiles in Eclipse environment with main function

Any idea how to get it works with kts
?

Thanks

Comment: `No persistence provider` doesn't necessarily mean that it can't read the `persistence.xml` (check you spelt it correct). Maybe it can't find the provider in the CLASSPATH ...

Comment: The error occurs in *compile-time* which means your code hasn't been ran. so I'm sure you didn't add any JPA dependencies in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Even by including jpa dependencies in the CLASSPATH, I still getting the same error when running the script
I added  eclipselink-2.6.4.jar and postgresql-9.4.jar in the CLASSPATH. Should I add something else?